# Flexbox Padding and Border generate an empty pixel after child element

Tags: css, flexbox, padding

For past hours I've been struggling with the following problem:

I have two `div` elements wrapped inside a contaier, which itself is wrapped inside multiple other divs.
The container `div` has `display:flex`.

I have created a **minimal code example** hosted on [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jzLpye) containing the same code listed in here

```
<div class="samples">
    <div class="sample">
        <div class="flex-parent">
            <div class="div1">  
                <div>I'm div 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="div2">I'm div 2</div>
        </div>                     
    </div>  
</div>
```

The CSS code is pretty straight forward. I want the first element the be the
size of its content and the second one to grow the remaining width

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.samples {
  background: #2B2B2B;
}
.samples .sample {
  padding: 50px;
}
.flex-parent { 
  border: 1px dashed green;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
}
.flex-parent .div1 {  
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: #D3394C;
}
.flex-parent .div2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

But the surprising problem was that the first element was not extending fully in terms of height and leaving an empty pixel space after him, as you can see in the image below (made from codepen)
[image]

**BUT**
Looks like the problem solves itself when you remove this part

```
.samples .sample {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

from the code, thus removing the padding of the `sample` wrapper.

**BUT2** it shouldn't have any influence on the elements inside the other container, should it?

It believe it should be related to `box-sizing: border-box`, but I cannot understand why the child elements behave in such a strange way, given the fact that it should correctly have 198px height and leave no empty space after it.

What is the idea behind this, could somebody please explain?

**EDIT1**: looks like the issue is only present in latest versions of desktop Chrome (65.0.3325.181) and Edge (41.16299.248.0)

**EDIT2**: on older versions of Chrome (42), it is working as intended.

Comment: Interesting at 51 px there is no problem, but at 49 px it is on top.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem in Chrome or Firefox. Codepen renders with no gap at the bottom.

Comment: @Michael_B The padding should be 50px to have the gap. I might have accidentally changed the padding and saved. Please retry

Comment: Looks like the problem is not reproducible on mobile Chrome though. I'm not sure why this happens

Comment: I have been able to reproduce it on Edge and Chrome on my laptop

Comment: I have updated to: Google Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (32-bit)
And the issue persists. Even though on Chrome 49 it wasn't there

Comment: The issue is not present in Firefox (from version 42 to present)

Comment: @Michael_B please check my newest edit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my display scaling 125%, that generated the gap. Bringing it back to 100% solved it.
There must be some issues inside chrome and edge engines (because it works well in Firefox).

For more information, follow the link https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8332